# Update Bootstrap Alert Text from AJAX Request Result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple AJAX request that updates some PHP session variables based on some selections in a table. It fires off an AJAX request when they make their selections. At the moment if there's an error with the AJAX request I'm displaying a generic error message by showing a hidden Bootstrap Alert

```html
<div id="alert_ajax_error" class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert" style="display:none">
  There was an error updating your selections - please contact the Support Desk
</div>
```

I would now like to change the generic error message (There was an error updating your selections - please contact the Support Desk) to one that shows the error string returned from the AJAX request.

Here's my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.btn-success').click(function() {
    var itemID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(itemID);
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('updateSelections.php', {
      itemID: itemID,
      selectionType: 'yes'
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        console.log(ajaxError);
        console.log('something was wrong with the ajax request');
        $this.closest('tr').addClass("warning");
        //make alert visible
        $("#alert_ajax_error").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        console.log('update successful - success add class to table row');
        $this.closest('tr').addClass("success");
        $this.closest('tr').removeClass("danger");
        //$(this).closest('tr').attr('class','success');
      }
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      console.log('ajax request failed');
      // no data available in this context
      $this.closest('tr').addClass("warning");
      //make alert visible
      $("#alert_ajax_error").show();
    });
  });
});
```

The ajaxError variable contains the string I would like to use in my alert. Is it possible to somehow use this and insert it into the alert that is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert your response via:

```
$('#alert_ajax_error').html(data);
```